# How can I fix provider.vault: no vault token found?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hashicorp-vault

Here're the [official docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/vault/latest/docs#token) about vault provider and the thing is:

```
provider "vault" {
  version = "2.10.0"
  address = "..."
}
```

I did set both `VAULT_ADDR` and `VAULT_TOKEN`:

```
terraform plan -lock=false dev/foo_dev
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

data.aws_iam_policy_document.foo_doc: Refreshing state...

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Error: Error running plan: 1 error occurred:
        * provider.vault: no vault token found
make: *** [plan] Error 1
✗ echo $VAULT_ADDR 
...
✗ echo $VAULT_TOKEN
...
```

> token - (Required) Vault token that will be used by Terraform to authenticate. May be set via the VAULT_TOKEN environment variable.

If I remove `address = "..."` I can see the same error so it can't retrieve `VAULT_ADDR` either.

Answer (score 3):

Did you export the variables? You need to use

```sh
export VAULT_TOKEN=s.123456789abc
export VAULT_ADDR=vault.company.org
```

not just

```sh
VAULT_TOKEN=s.123456789abc
VAULT_ADDR=vault.company.org
```

otherwise `terraform` won't see those variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Env:VAULT_TOKEN="Your Token data (Click your profile on top right and copy token)"
$Env:VAULT_ADDR="https://Vault.company.com(Vault URL)"
```

Enter this info on your powershell command prompt/VSD prior to doing terraform plan.